# How should I modify my wall such that I will not hear the electric devices noise from my neighbour?

Tags: walls, noise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I soundproof my vaulted townhouse wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7002/how-do-i-soundproof-my-vaulted-townhouse-wall)

My neighbor seem to have place a electric device (maybe aircon or a humidifier) on a wall that is shared between them and my house.

How should I modify my wall such that the noise is being inside my neighbor house and will not travel to my house?

The noise heard is a low humming sound and my neighbor since to turn on almost 18 hours a day 7 times a week.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the questions tagged [noise-reduction](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noise-reduction), or [sound-proofing](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-proofing)?

Comment: These questions might be helpful: [Thin walls means lots of noise](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5947/thin-walls-means-lots-of-noise), [reducing external sound from entering a room](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2218/what-are-some-cost-effective-tips-for-reducing-external-sound-from-entering-a-ro), [How can I fix the noise level in my home?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11215/how-can-i-fix-the-noise-level-in-my-home).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From most effective to least:

- The best method of noise reduction is actually to minimise the noise at source. Have you spoken to your neighbour? Perhaps there is the option of isolating the device from the wall itself, or using a mount with rubber bushes to reduce the transmitted vibrations.

Failing that, the two ways sound will propagate are through solids and through the air. Adding sound proofing insulation will reduce the sound transmitted through the air - but to be honest, your existing insulation in the wall should already be quite effective.

- To reduce the sound that is directly transmitted you can add rubber spacers inside the wall, to the connecting joists, stubs etc but this requires taking your wall apart!
- So the remaining thing to look at is a sound proofing wall covering, which can be very effective. Some are easily suitable for covering a wall without looking too industrial.

Comment: Isolating the device from the supporting structure is the only effective solution. Anything else will only help marginally and be more expensive. Talk to your neighbor.